# How to update screen or state on coming back to route using pop

Tags: flutter

I want to update a screen on coming back to that screen using `Navigator.pop`.
E.g. I have `Home` Screen and Some steps screens (`Step1`, `Step2`, `Step3`, `Step4`)

Home screen is a stateful widget and shows number of steps completed.

The flow is like

> Home => Step1 => Step2 => Step3 => Step4

On any step, on pressing back or pressing close button, it should go back to `Home` screen and home screen should show updated state of steps completed. So i am navigating to next steps in steps screen using `Navigator.popAndPushNamed` so that `Navigator.pop` will go to `Home` screen.

And using `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Step1').then` in `Home` screen to update it.
But the problem is `.then` is called just on `Step1` itself because it got popped and if user goes like

> Home => Step1 => Step2 => Step3 => Home (using pop)

Home scren will only show Step1 is completed because when going from `Step1 to Step2`, its `.then` callback was called and when coming to `Home` from `Step3` using `Navigator.pop`, no code is being executed and i am unable to update the Home Screen.
I know i can use `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Home')` from steps to go to home screen but it doesn't looks ok (it looks like Home screen was pushed on it instead animation should be like it goes back).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable in your previous page which will keep a track, if you are coming from the next page and return a boolean true variable, stating that it has returned from the previous activity. You can use that varible in your init method and if the value of that variable is true you can just fire an event which will return appropriate state.

Comment: how would i return a variable? and exactly i want some place where i can execute the code when it came back to that screen and initState doesn't get called again when i come back to the screen after `Navigator.pop` (i don't know if there is any method which gets called)

Comment: This is an example to return data from pop. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: yes but the thing is you can only return variable from the next screen and the callback to process the return value gets executed immediately when next screen is pop which doesn't necessarily mean you are on the previous screen
e.g. i am on `ScreenA`, went to `ScreenB` using `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'ScreenB').then((value) { debugPrint('screen is poped from screenA'); })`
and from `ScreenB` went to `ScreenC` using `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, 'ScreenC')`
So here it prints `screen is poped from screenA` even though we are on `ScreenC`

Answer (score 1):

found the solution using `RouteObserver` and implemented something like example given in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html

The method i was looking for `didPopNext` of RouteAware.

Answer (score 0):

> Check this, It's Working For Me!
>
> ```
> Navigator.of(context).push(route).then((val){
>     //you can update you data here, when coming back
> })
> ```

Comment: as i said in question, in this case, the callback to `.then` is called just after `route` is popped from the Navigator and it doesn't mean that it came back to previous screen. Because from another screen, i am doing `popAndPush` which replaces the current screen with another screen.